# The System Running In Low Graphics Mode’ Error. Guides will help

Tags: nvidia, windows-8

Hello Ask Ubuntu community. I've been trying to setup / load Ubuntu for a while now, but It won't let me set it up. I get the error "The system is running in low graphics mode" and I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card.
I put the ISO file on a USB, it's on the USB and all just fine. It doesn't give me any boot options when I start up my PC so I have to go to Charmbar > Settings > Update and Recovery > Recovery then restart through Advanced Setup to load Ubuntu for the first time. I tried following guides by doing `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates` in terminal but they don't work. The reason they don't work is because they require me to reboot the computer. Like I said earlier I can't reboot my PC as once I do it just goes straight back to Windows 8.1. So whenever I go to load Ubuntu again it just restores back to where the low-graphics mode is. So I was wondering how do I bypass the low-graphics mode when I have the problems that I do?

Comment: What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3

Answer (score 0):

You install a wrong driver for this card. Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Comment: For all the packages it says "Package 'blank' is not installed so not removed" When i try to install nvidia-346 it says "Unable to locate package nvidia-346"

Comment: Added a command to my answer.

Comment: Okay worked so far, but what do i do after? Restart the machine (which i cant due to what I said in the post) or what other method would get rid of the low graphics mode error?

Comment: I do not understand why can't you reboot. Did you do it booting from USB? Then you can boot with `nomodeset` parameter, install Ubuntu and then install this driver.

Comment: I cant reboot because when I it loads to windows and doesn't show a boot menu. There for I have to enter Ubuntu through the windows advanced settings.

Comment: When I reboot I have to type the commands all over again lime the whole setup progress restores from the beginning